# What is the proper way of changing button-captions from a variable with jquery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

In a jquery UI Dialog, I want the **value** of som variables put into the buttons.

If I for instance have:

```
var okButtonText= 'Ok';
var cancelButtonText= 'Cancel';
```

and I want the buttons to set to value Ok and to Cancel respectivly:

```
$(dialogObj).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "okButtonText": function() {             
          $( this ).dialog( "close");
        },
        "cancelButtonText": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
       }
});
```

When I do like above the buttons are named okButtonText and cancelButtonText (I want them to be named OK and Cancel)

If I try without quotes:

```
$(dialogObj).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        okButtonText: function() {             
          $( this ).dialog( "close");
        },
        cancelButtonText: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
       }
});
```

it's the same effect.

I guess I COULD change the buttons with  open-option in the jquery UI Dialog (with changing the html of each button), but that seems totally wrong and I just have a feeling that there is a much better solution out there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `text` option of your [`buttons`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons):

> Specifies which buttons should be displayed on the dialog. The context
>   of the callback is the dialog element; if you need access to the
>   button, it is available as the target of the event object. Multiple
>   types supported: Object: The keys are the button labels and the values
>   are the callbacks for when the associated button is clicked. Array:
>   Each element of the array must be an object defining the attributes,
>   properties, and event handlers to set on the button.

Code:

```
$(".selector").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: okButtonText,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, {
        text: cancelButtonText,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld you are welcome; if solved consider to accept the answer using the green mark

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried to click before some times, but I hade to wait 3 minutes and that was far too long ;-) Then I just forgot about it. Of course I would accept your answer! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld no prolem, you are welcome! Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thanks. Happy coding for you to! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `text` option here:

```
$(".selector").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: You can pass it directly to the text value.